# Is there a way to defer an ActiveRecord query (like QuerySet in Django)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to build a query in sections without evaluating the final statement until a later time in Ruby on Rails.

Specifically this behavior (copied from Djano docs):

> a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and
>   generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No
>   database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate
>   the queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works by default unless you access the results.  That is, you can put this into your controller:

```
@widgets = Widget.enabled
@widgets = @widgets.where(foo: 'bar')
# ... more conditions here if you want ...
```

And then in your view put this:

```
<%- @widgets.each do |w| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The DB query won't run until that `@widgets.each` line.

You can test this by using `logger.info` statements in your control to see where the query is actually being executed.

Comment: You're right. I never realized this because the console doesn't work this way.